# Can I sell in Canada a product patented United States?

Tags: us, canada, sell

**Can I sell in Canada a product patented the United States?**

Can I sell in Canada a product patented in the United States?  How can I know the united States Patent has registered an international license or not? I am interested in [US patent 7,264,189](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7264189B2/en?oq=us7264189), please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a corresponding Canadian application CA2444353A1 HAND-HELD FOOD PROCESSOR.

Patents are territorial and no "international license" of the U.S. patent would be relevant in Canada. The application above is not not granted as a patent as of 11/16/2020.

Answer (score 1):

To add to George White's answer, the cited US patent should expire in the US as of April 19, 2021. According to Google Patents, the Canadian application [CA2444353C](https://patents.google.com/patent/CA2444353C/en?oq=us7264189) should it get approved would expire about a year later on April 11, 2022. Once a patent expires, it is no longer a concern from an infringement aspect. This doesn't mean other, more recent patents aren't also a concern.